# What made the current life of Lucy special?

Tags: the-devils-hour

**Note: the question below is a huge spoiler for *The Devil's Hour* based on the explanations provided in the season 1 finale.<sup>1</sup>**

According to Gideon, life is relieved in loops, and he is the only one who can change the fate of others, i.e. by slashing the tires of a car that was supposed to crash hours later. Those that he has saved are often experiencing "ripples" - views from the world that were supposed to originally happen.

Gideon says that he has intervened in Lucy's life in her childhood, by preventing her mother's suicide, which explains the "ripples" that Lucy can see occasionally. But then he says, that this life is special, because she has a son - Isaac - who "is not supposed to exist, because he never existed".

But what made Isaac's existence possible? Gideon apparently saved Lucy's mother more than once so this wasn't the first loop.

<sup>1 I don't want to hide the whole question in the spoiler tag</sup>